# Preempt a hot loop thread from user space

Tags: java, c, multithreading

I have an idea and it's kind of complicated and you must be familiar with assembly and multithreading to understand why I want to do this.

Did you ever notice that the cancel button never does anything when the program you are running is in a hot loop? But if you put an if statement in the hot loop you slow it down drastically.

In the Linux kernel, processes are scheduled by a timer onto the CPU by an interrupt when the timeslice has expired. See the schedule method in kernel/sched/core.c

Now in user space in Java and C programs, you have a thread in a hot loop unless you put an if statement inside the hot loop to check an aborted flag you cannot interrupt the hot loop from user space.

Only the kernel can preempt a thread.

But I have an idea on how we can preempt a thread in C programming from a userspace.

We can disassemble a function address to a RET to get its assembly. We can therefore identify the conditional jumps of the loop. We can introduce a go-to statement of __sched_yield() after the hot loop we can identify where in memory the relative address of the Sched yield from the disassembly.

From this, we can virtually interrupt a user thread from user space. Shall need to madvise/memprotect the executable code to update the conditional jump statement to jump to the goto statement.

What do you think? How easy is this?

- [How to learn the size of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966856/find-size-of-a-function-in-c)
- [How to disassemble a function with libopcodes](https://blog.yossarian.net/2019/05/18/Basic-disassembly-with-libopcodes)
- [How to update memory of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447013/how-to-write-self-modifying-code-in-c)

Comment: I think it is a bad idea.  Just do it the normal way.  If the overhead of a system call is too great ... the chances are that you are misusing preemption.  (How often do you expect the user to hit the "cancel" button?   Just wire it up to `pthread_cancel` or `pthread_kill`.)

Comment: The problem is the cost of interactivity, putting an if (cancelled) in your hot loop slows down your code significantly.

Comment: So use `pthread_kill`.  I suggested >two< alternatives.   Anyhow your approach is liable to run into problems with portability and optimizing compilers and stuff like that.  (And if you turn down / off the optimization, you most likely lose the performance you gained by not checking a flag.)

Comment: The problem is most signal handlers are in their own thread, the signal handlers cannot kill another thread. You would need to put your signal handlers in the hot thread and update the loop invariants to stop. You cannot stop a hot loop in a signal handlers unless you change the loop invariants. You could put your looping variable as a global and maybe this would work to prempt a hot loop.

Comment: I'm interested in N:M schedulers (where N is the number of kernel threads and M is the number of green threads) and multiplexing green threads or goroutines onto multiple kernel threads. I want to solve the resource starvation problem. I've read the Go scheduler and Linux scheduler and I want to schedule in user space that requires preemption.

Comment: “*Did you ever notice that the cancel button never does anything when the program you are running is in a hot loop?*” No, not when the programmer did their job right. But what does your “*idea on how we can preempt a thread in C programming*” have to do with your answer showing Java code doing a simple polling loop? It’s neither C programming nor preemption.

Comment: I added a C version of the same program. Did you read and understand the code? It's not polling. You may have read the code before it was a multiplexing scheduler. Read the updated code.

Comment: I added a Rust version of the same program.

Comment: Cool idea, but: "But if you put an if statement in the hot loop you slow it down drastically." Does it really? wouldn't the branch predictor very reliable predict the path taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, C and Rust you can preempt a thread in a hot loop by directly changing the looped variable to go beyond the loop invariant. You can do this from any thread.

If you need to use the loop variable (you probably do), make sure you copy it into a variable like this, or you'll have a data race:

```
for (initialVar(0, 0), int loopVal = 0; getValue(0) < getLimit(0); loopVal = increment(0)) {
                                        Math.sqrt(loopVal);
                                    }
```

Or

```
 for (int loopVal = 0; m->value[0] < m->limit[0]; loopVal = m->value[0]++) {
            
            sqrt(loopVal);
          }
```

You can create cancellable APIs with this approach, your cancel token can represent all the loops indexes that the code is in. So you can create profoundly responsive code. Even if you are deep in encryption or compression or uploading data. As long as you're not in a syscall.

I also pasted a C version of this sourcecode below the Java version. The Rust version is below the C version

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Scheduler {

    public static class KernelThread extends Thread {
        public Map<LightWeightThread, Boolean> scheduled = new HashMap<>();

        public void preempt() {
            for (LightWeightThread thread : scheduled.keySet()) {
                scheduled.put(thread, false);
                for (int loop = 0 ; loop < thread.getLoops(); loop++) {
                    thread.preempt(loop);
                }
            }

        }
        public void addLightWeightThread(LightWeightThread thread) {
            scheduled.put(thread, false);
        }

        public boolean isScheduled(LightWeightThread lightWeightThread) {
            return scheduled.get(lightWeightThread);
        }
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                LightWeightThread previous = null;
                for (LightWeightThread thread : scheduled.keySet()) {
                    scheduled.put(thread, false);
                }
                for (LightWeightThread thread : scheduled.keySet()) {
                    if (previous != null) {
                        scheduled.put(previous, false);
                    }
                    scheduled.put(thread, true);
                    thread.run();

                    previous = thread;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public interface Preemptible {
        void registerLoop(int name, int defaultValue, int limit);
        int increment(int name);
        boolean isPreempted(int name);
        int getLimit(int name);
        int getValue(int name);
        void preempt(int id);
        int getLoops();
    }

    public static abstract class LightWeightThread implements Preemptible {
        public int kernelThreadId;
        public int threadId;
        public KernelThread parent;
        AtomicInteger[] values = new AtomicInteger[1];
        int[] limits = new int[1];
        boolean[] preempted = new boolean[1];
        int[] remembered = new int[1];
        public LightWeightThread(int kernelThreadId, int threadId, KernelThread parent) {
            this.kernelThreadId = kernelThreadId;
            this.threadId = threadId;
            this.parent = parent;
            for (int i = 0 ; i < values.length; i++) {
                values[i] = new AtomicInteger();
            }
        }
        public void run() {

        }

        public void registerLoop(int name, int defaultValue, int limit) {
            if (preempted.length > name && remembered[name] < limit) {
                values[name].set(remembered[name]);
                limits[name] = limit;
            } else {
                values[name].set(defaultValue);
                limits[name] = limit;
            }
            preempted[name] = false;

        }

        public int increment(int name) {
            return values[name].incrementAndGet();
        }

        public boolean isPreempted(int name) {
            return preempted[name];
        }

        public int getLimit(int name) {
            return limits[name];
        }

        public int getValue(int name) {
            return values[name].get();
        }

        public int initialVar(int name, int value) {
            values[name].set(value);
            return value;
        }

        public void preempt(int id) {
            remembered[id] = values[id].get();
            preempted[id] = true;
            while (!values[id].compareAndSet(values[id].get(), limits[id])){};
        }

        public int getLoops() {
            return values.length;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<KernelThread> kernelThreads = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            KernelThread kt = new KernelThread();
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++) {
                LightWeightThread lightWeightThread = new LightWeightThread(i, j, kt) {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                            while (this.parent.isScheduled(this)) {
                                System.out.println(String.format("%d %d", this.kernelThreadId, this.threadId));
                                registerLoop(0, 0, 10000000);
                                for (initialVar(0, 0); getValue(0) < getLimit(0); increment(0)) {
                                    Math.sqrt(getValue(0));
                                }

                                if (isPreempted(0)) {
                                    System.out.println(String.format("%d %d: %d was preempted !%d < %d", this.kernelThreadId, this.threadId, 0, values[0].get(), limits[0]));
                                }
                            }

                        }

                };
                kt.addLightWeightThread(lightWeightThread);
            }

            kernelThreads.add(kt);
        }
        for (KernelThread kt : kernelThreads) {
            kt.start();
        }
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (KernelThread kt : kernelThreads) {

                    kt.preempt();
                }
            }
        }, 10, 10);

        for (KernelThread kt : kernelThreads) {
            kt.join();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the C  version of the same thing:

```
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <math.h>

 #define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
         do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

 #define handle_error(msg) \
         do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

struct lightweight_thread {
  int thread_num;
  volatile int preempted;
  int num_loops;
  int *limit;
  volatile int *value;
  int *remembered;
  int kernel_thread_num;
  struct lightweight_thread* (*user_function) (struct lightweight_thread*);
};

 struct thread_info {    /* Used as argument to thread_start() */
     pthread_t thread_id;        /* ID returned by pthread_create() */
     int       thread_num;       /* Application-defined thread # */
     char     *argv_string;      /* From command-line argument */
    int lightweight_threads_num;
  struct lightweight_thread *user_threads;
  volatile int running;
 };

struct timer_thread {
  pthread_t thread_id;
  struct thread_info *all_threads;
  int num_threads;
  int lightweight_threads_num;
  int delay;
  volatile int running;
};

static void *
timer_thread_start(void *arg) {
  int iterations = 0;
  struct timer_thread *timer_thread = arg;
  int msec = 0, trigger = timer_thread->delay; /* 10ms */
clock_t before = clock();
while (timer_thread->running == 1 && iterations < 100000) {
do {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < timer_thread->num_threads; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < timer_thread->all_threads[i].lightweight_threads_num; j++) {
      // printf("Preempting kernel thread %d user thread %d\n", i, j);
      timer_thread->all_threads[i].user_threads[j].preempted = 0;
      
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0 ; i < timer_thread->num_threads; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < timer_thread->all_threads[i].lightweight_threads_num; j++) {
      
      
      // printf("Preempting kernel thread %d user thread %d\n", i, j);
      for (int loop = 0; loop < timer_thread->all_threads[i].user_threads[j].num_loops; loop++) {
        timer_thread->all_threads[i].user_threads[j].remembered[loop] = timer_thread->all_threads[i].user_threads[j].value[loop];
        timer_thread->all_threads[i].user_threads[j].value[loop] = timer_thread->all_threads[i].user_threads[j].limit[loop];
      }
      
    }
  }

  clock_t difference = clock() - before;
  msec = difference * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  iterations++;
} while ( msec < trigger && iterations < 100000 );

// printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds (%d iterations)\n",
//  msec/1000, msec%1000, iterations);
  }
  return 0;
}

 /* Thread start function: display address near top of our stack,
    and return upper-cased copy of argv_string. */

 static void *
 thread_start(void *arg)
 {
     struct thread_info *tinfo = arg;
     char *uargv;

     printf("Thread %d: top of stack near %p; argv_string=%s\n",
             tinfo->thread_num, (void *) &tinfo, tinfo->argv_string);

     uargv = strdup(tinfo->argv_string);
     if (uargv == NULL)
         handle_error("strdup");

     for (char *p = uargv; *p != '\0'; p++) {
         *p = toupper(*p);
       
       }

    while (tinfo->running == 1) {
      for (int i = 0 ; i < tinfo->lightweight_threads_num; i++) {
        tinfo->user_threads[i].preempted = 0;
        
      }
      int previous = -1;
       for (int i = 0 ; i < tinfo->lightweight_threads_num; i++) {
         if (previous != -1) {
           tinfo->user_threads[previous].preempted = 0;
         }
        tinfo->user_threads[i].preempted = 1;
        tinfo->user_threads[i].user_function(&tinfo->user_threads[i]);
         previous = i;
      } 
    }

   
     return uargv;
 }

void
register_loop(int index, int value, struct lightweight_thread* m, int limit) {
  if (m->remembered[index] == -1) {
    m->limit[index] = limit;
    m->value[index] = value;
  } else {
    m->limit[index] = limit;
    m->value[index] = m->remembered[index];
  }
}

int
lightweight_thread_function(struct lightweight_thread* m)
{
    
    while (m->preempted != 0) {
      register_loop(0, 0, m, 100000000);
      for (; m->value[0] < m->limit[0]; m->value[0]++) {
        
        sqrt(m->value[0]);
      }
      printf("Kernel thread %d User thread %d ran\n", m->kernel_thread_num, m->thread_num);
      
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}

struct lightweight_thread*
create_lightweight_threads(int kernel_thread_num, int num_threads) {
struct lightweight_thread *lightweight_threads = 
  calloc(num_threads, sizeof(*lightweight_threads));
       if (lightweight_threads == NULL)
           handle_error("calloc lightweight threads");
  for (int i = 0 ; i < num_threads ; i++) {
    lightweight_threads[i].kernel_thread_num = kernel_thread_num;
    lightweight_threads[i].thread_num = i;
    lightweight_threads[i].num_loops = 1;
    lightweight_threads[i].user_function = lightweight_thread_function;
    int *remembered = calloc(lightweight_threads[i].num_loops, sizeof(*remembered));
    int *value = calloc(lightweight_threads[i].num_loops, sizeof(*value));
    int *limit = calloc(lightweight_threads[i].num_loops, sizeof(*limit));
    lightweight_threads[i].remembered = remembered;
    lightweight_threads[i].value = value;
    lightweight_threads[i].limit = limit;
    for (int j = 0 ; j < lightweight_threads[i].num_loops ; j++) {
    lightweight_threads[i].remembered[j] = -1;
      }
  }
    return lightweight_threads;
}

 int
 main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     int s, timer_s, opt, num_threads;
     pthread_attr_t attr;
     pthread_attr_t timer_attr;
     ssize_t stack_size;
     void *res;
     int timer_result;

     /* The "-s" option specifies a stack size for our threads. */

     stack_size = 16384ul;
     num_threads = 5;
   
     while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "t:")) != -1) {
         switch (opt) {
         
        case 't':
             num_threads = strtoul(optarg, NULL, 0);
             break;
           
         default:
             fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-t thread-size] arg...\n",
                     argv[0]);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
     }

     

     /* Initialize thread creation attributes. */

     s = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
     if (s != 0)
         handle_error_en(s, "pthread_attr_init");
     timer_s = pthread_attr_init(&timer_attr);
     if (timer_s != 0)
         handle_error_en(s, "pthread_attr_init timer_s");

   
     if (stack_size > 0) {
         s = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, stack_size);
         int t = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&timer_attr, stack_size);
       if (t != 0)
             handle_error_en(t, "pthread_attr_setstacksize timer");
         if (s != 0)
             handle_error_en(s, "pthread_attr_setstacksize");
     }

     /* Allocate memory for pthread_create() arguments. */

     struct thread_info *tinfo = calloc(num_threads, sizeof(*tinfo));
     if (tinfo == NULL)
         handle_error("calloc");
    for (int tnum = 0 ; tnum < num_threads; tnum++) {
      tinfo[tnum].running = 1;
    }
   struct timer_thread *timer_info = calloc(1, sizeof(*timer_info));
     timer_info->running = 1;
      timer_info->delay = 10;
     timer_info->num_threads = num_threads;
      
     if (timer_info == NULL)
         handle_error("calloc timer thread");

     /* Create one thread for each command-line argument. */
    timer_info->all_threads = tinfo;
     for (int tnum = 0; tnum < num_threads; tnum++) {
         tinfo[tnum].thread_num = tnum + 1;
         tinfo[tnum].argv_string = argv[0];

        struct lightweight_thread *lightweight_threads = create_lightweight_threads(tnum, num_threads);
        tinfo[tnum].user_threads = lightweight_threads;
        tinfo[tnum].lightweight_threads_num = num_threads;
         /* The pthread_create() call stores the thread ID into
            corresponding element of tinfo[]. */

         s = pthread_create(&tinfo[tnum].thread_id, &attr,
                            &thread_start, &tinfo[tnum]);
         if (s != 0)
             handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create");
     }

   s = pthread_create(&timer_info[0].thread_id, &timer_attr,
                            &timer_thread_start, &timer_info[0]);
         if (s != 0)
             handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create");

     /* Destroy the thread attributes object, since it is no
        longer needed. */

     s = pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
     if (s != 0)
         handle_error_en(s, "pthread_attr_destroy");
     s = pthread_attr_destroy(&timer_attr);
     if (s != 0)
         handle_error_en(s, "pthread_attr_destroy timer");

     /* Now join with each thread, and display its returned value. */

   s = pthread_join(timer_info->thread_id, &timer_result);
         if (s != 0)
             handle_error_en(s, "pthread_join");

         printf("Joined timer thread");
   

     for (int tnum = 0; tnum < num_threads; tnum++) {
          tinfo[tnum].running = 0;
         s = pthread_join(tinfo[tnum].thread_id, &res);
         if (s != 0)
             handle_error_en(s, "pthread_join");

         printf("Joined with thread %d; returned value was %s\n",
                 tinfo[tnum].thread_num, (char *) res);
         free(res);      /* Free memory allocated by thread */
       for (int user_thread_num = 0 ; user_thread_num < num_threads; user_thread_num++) {
         
           free(tinfo[tnum].user_threads[user_thread_num].remembered);
           free(tinfo[tnum].user_threads[user_thread_num].value);
         free(tinfo[tnum].user_threads[user_thread_num].limit);
         
       }
       free(tinfo[tnum].user_threads);
     }
   
   
   
     free(timer_info);
     free(tinfo);
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

The Rust version uses unsafe.

```
extern crate timer;
extern crate chrono;

use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicI32, Ordering};
use std::{time};

struct LightweightThread {
  thread_num: i32, 
  preempted: AtomicI32,
  num_loops: i32,
  limit: Vec<AtomicI32>,
  value: Vec<AtomicI32>,
  remembered: Vec<AtomicI32>,
  kernel_thread_num: i32,
  lightweight_thread: fn(&mut LightweightThread)
}
fn register_loop(loopindex: usize, initialValue: i32, limit: i32, _thread: &mut LightweightThread) {
  if _thread.remembered[loopindex].load(Ordering::Relaxed) < _thread.limit[loopindex].load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
    _thread.value[loopindex].store( _thread.remembered[loopindex].load(Ordering::Relaxed), Ordering::Relaxed);
    _thread.limit[loopindex].store(limit, Ordering::Relaxed);
  } else {
    _thread.value[loopindex].store(initialValue, Ordering::Relaxed);
    _thread.limit[loopindex].store(limit, Ordering::Relaxed);
  }
  
}
fn lightweight_thread(_thread: &mut LightweightThread) {
  register_loop(0usize, 0, 1000000, _thread);
  while _thread.preempted.load(Ordering::Relaxed) == 1 {
    while _thread.value[0].load(Ordering::Relaxed) < _thread.limit[0].load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
      let i = _thread.value[0].load(Ordering::Relaxed);
      f64::sqrt(i.into());
      _thread.value[0].fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
  }
  println!("Kernel thread {} User thread {}", _thread.kernel_thread_num, _thread.thread_num)
}

fn main() {
  println!("Hello, world!");
  let timer = timer::Timer::new();
  static mut threads:Vec<LightweightThread> = Vec::new();
  let mut thread_handles = Vec::new();
  for kernel_thread_num in 1..=5 {
    
    let thread_join_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
      
      
      
      for i in 1..=5 {
        let mut lthread = LightweightThread {
          thread_num: i,
          preempted: AtomicI32::new(0),
          num_loops: 1,
          limit: Vec::new(),
          value: Vec::new(),
          remembered: Vec::new(),
          kernel_thread_num: kernel_thread_num.clone(),
          lightweight_thread: lightweight_thread
        };
        
        lthread.limit.push(AtomicI32::new(-1));
      
        lthread.value.push(AtomicI32::new(-1));
      
        lthread.remembered.push(AtomicI32::new(1));
        
        
        unsafe {
          threads.push(lthread);
        }
      }

      
      
      loop {
        let mut previous:Option<&mut LightweightThread> = None;
        unsafe {
          for (_pos, current_thread) in threads.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            
            if current_thread.kernel_thread_num != kernel_thread_num {
              
              continue;
            }
            if !previous.is_none() {
              previous.unwrap().preempted.store(0, Ordering::Relaxed)
            }
            current_thread.preempted.store(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
            (current_thread.lightweight_thread)(current_thread);
            previous = Some(current_thread);
            // println!("Running")
          }
        }
      } // loop forever
  }); // thread
    
    thread_handles.push(thread_join_handle);
  } // thread generation



 

let timer_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
  
  unsafe {

   loop {
  
  
    for thread in threads.iter() {
      thread.preempted.store(0, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
    let mut previous:Option<usize> = None;
    for (index,  thread) in threads.iter_mut().enumerate() {
      if !previous.is_none() {
        threads[previous.unwrap()].preempted.store(0, Ordering::Relaxed);
      }
      previous = Some(index);
      for loopindex in 0..thread.num_loops {
        thread.remembered[loopindex as usize].store(thread.value[loopindex as usize].load(Ordering::Relaxed), Ordering::Relaxed);
        thread.value[loopindex as usize].store(thread.limit[loopindex as usize].load(Ordering::Relaxed), Ordering::Relaxed);
        
      }
      thread.preempted.store(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }

let ten_millis = time::Duration::from_millis(10);


thread::sleep(ten_millis);
     
  } // loop

} // unsafe
  
}); // end of thread
  timer_handle.join();
   for thread in thread_handles {
    thread.join();
  }

  

}
```

Comment: Well yea ... but this is not "preemption" in the normal sense, or in the sense that you seemed to be asking in the Question.   And your Java implementation is NOT thread-safe since use of the shared loop variable is not properly synchronized.  (You would have the same problem if you translated this into C, I think.)

Comment: It's not thread safe but it doesn't matter in this case, we don't care about the cancelled iteration of the loop. I just wrote a multiplexing scheduler which avoids resource starvation. For memory visibility you could change the loop variable to be volatile, then there would be a full memory barrier. You can find my multiplexing of lightweight threads onto OS kernel threads here - https://github.com/samsquire/preemptible-thread/blob/master/src/main/java/Scheduler.java

Comment: The hot loop's contents is not being preempted, if there is an expensive statement in there, that wouldn't be preempted. But the next iteration of the loop is preempted with this design which is what I want for responsiveness. This is responsive to user behaviour without introducing lag due to an if statement which is what I wanted. I just need to learn how to do this in C.

Comment: You do it in C the same way ;-). (Seriously, I'm not sure which part of the approach wouldn't work there.) By the way, are you sure that hash computation  and hashmap access are indeed faster than a perfectly predictable condition?

Comment: Peter, thank you for looking at my question and answer. I could change the hashmap to a simple array of integers and have a convention where loop variable is at position n and limit is at position n + 1. This would remove the overhead of the hashmap. It was just  for convenience of implementation.

Comment: Also Thank you Steven for giving me the idea of this approach.

Comment: Also, if you are happy with aborting only upon completion of an iteration, *would* there have to be be an additional conditional jump at all? E.g. `for(int i=0; i<n & !aborted; i++)`would not have one, and I think even the code for `&&` can be jump-less if there aren't any side effects.

Comment: *"It's not thread safe but it doesn't matter in this case ..."* - Actually I think it does matter.  The thread-safety issue *could* manifest as the reading thread never seeing the update from the writing thread, and therefore never being preempted.  Or even worse, unsynchronized updates to a shared `HashMap` could corrupt it, leading to things like unexpected NPEs.  (Depending on the Java version ...)

Comment: I updated the code to use arrays for loop variable, limit and remembered. I also replaced the code to the multiplexing scheduler which is slightly different to the original code I placed here. It has 5 kernel threads that load balances 5 light weight threads They should all run evenly and not starve as the equivalent of the while (true) and the long loop they are each preempted.

Comment: Steven, you are right regarding the hashmap and NPEs which I experienced before while iterating and arraycopying while being modified in other threads. But I replaced the limit and loop variable hashmap with an array. Do you still see there being a multithreading issue with this approach? I could also change the array to be volatile so any update will have a memory fence and be visible to the looping thread.

Comment: Maybe.  The code is very complicated to reason about from a thread-safety perspective.   If it was my (Java) code, I would use `Thread.interrupt()` etcetera.  Much easier to reason about.

Comment: The looping thread reads the loop variable and limit at the beginning of an iteration. The writing thread writes to the looping thread. It's possible that the writing thread preemption gets overwritten if the looping thread is incrementing at the same time the writing thread preempts. But I've been running it all this time and it hasn't frozen on me yet, the problem would correct itself on the next iteration. I could change the loop variable to an AtomicInteger and compare and swap with the last value and it would be a lock free algorithm. The problem is the increment(0), a RW from both thread

Comment: Just occurred to me that the writing thread doesn't READ, it only writes the limit to the looping variable. But its changes could still be overwritten by the ++ I don't know how Java implements ++ if it's two operations or one.

Comment: I changed the code to use compareAndSet. In theory it's thread safe now. As the compareAndSet shall only work if the value was what it was read to be.

Comment: I added a C version of the preempting multiplexer scheduler. It doesn't use compareAndSet as I need to learn how to do that in C. It seems to work.